# CSS alternative for display:box for IE and Opera?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opera

I am using display:box for a flexible width div with three boxes of equal size and with equal spacing.  This works fine for Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but not in IE and Opera.  I am wondering what the best alternative method for IE and Opera would be.  Here is the display:box CSS:

```
.box {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    width: 100%;
}

.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    width: 0;
}

.box2, .box3 {  
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.bodhitreebrighton.org.uk/about.html).

I'd be glad to hear of an alternative method for achieving a similar result in IE and Opera.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: It is worth pointing out that Opera now supports Flexbox with the standard spec: display: flex; and IE10 supports it with the slightly older version: display: flexbox; IE11 will use the standard syntax (same as Opera, and Firefox 22+)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Flexie](http://flexiejs.com/) implements support for this in browsers that do not natively support `display: box;`.

Comment: Thanks.  That looks like what I am after and I have used the flexie [test page](http://flexiejs.com/playground/?random) in Opera and IE and can see that it works OK.  From the source code of this test page it seems like I only need to add jQuery and flexie.js to my page to get this working, but I have done so and it's not working on my pages.  Are you aware of anything else I need to do?

Comment: I have also implemented my own [test page](http://www.bodhitreebrighton.org.uk/test.html), which as you can see, if you look in Opera and IE, isn't working correctly. It should have three boxes side-by-side.

Comment: I have received a message from the developer of Flexie, stating "Flexie can only read styles via <link /> element. Can't do <style> blocks, sorry."  So I presume that this is why it is not working, though I don't understand what he means and I haven't heard back from him!

Comment: This means that for Flexie to work on your styles, they must be added to your page using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="filename.css">`.