# IE CSS "display:box" alternative using Flexie not displaying correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, opera

I'm using [Flexie](http://flexiejs.com/) `display: box;`  to be able to use the display box with `IE`.

as shown in the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873753/css-alternative-for-displaybox-for-ie-and-opera)

I have 3 boxes, the middle one is of `fixed width: 1138px`
the left and right box stretch to fit.

But can't seem to overcome a problem:
the right box is jumping to the next line.

here is the html code:

```
<div class="wraper-top">
<div id="header-left">..</div>
<header class="header">..</header>
<div id="header-right">..</div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
.wraper-top {
width:100%;
height:95px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
display: box;
box-align: start;

}



#header-center { width:1138px; height:48px; display: inline-block} 

#header-left {
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
background-color: #000000;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
height:48px;
margin:25px 18px 0px 0px;
}

.header {
position:relative;
z-index:1001;
padding:25px 0px 20px 0px;
width:1138px;
display:block;
}

#header-right {
background-color:#000000;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
height:48px;
margin:25px 0px 0px 18px;
}
```

and this is the page demonstrating the issue:
[preview site](http://tempsite.info.previewdns.com/)

Comment: For Opera, you should use the standard unprefixed display; flex; syntax. Will also work with IE11. For IE10 you should add the slightly older display: -ms-flexbox syntax.

Comment: thanks @David Storey.it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the improved code for ie10 thanks to @David Storey

```
.wraper-top {
width:100%;
height:95px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
display: -moz-box;
display: -webkit-box;
display: box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
box-align: start;

}


#header-left {
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
background-color: #000000;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
height:48px;
margin:25px 18px 0px 0px;
-ms-flex:1;
}

.header {
position:relative;
z-index:1001;
padding:25px 0px 20px 0px;
width:1138px;
display:block;
-ms-flex:938px;
}

#header-right {
background-color:#000000;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex:1;
height:48px;
margin:25px 0px 0px 18px;

}
```