# CSS Display class not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, flexbox

I've got an active state drop-down menu set to:

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -ms-flexbox;
```

Works great on all browsers, but, with Internet Explorer - the background color stops after the first element.

Can't figure out what the issue is here.

http://soakandswim.com/pools/inground --> this is the website
Any insight is appreciated!!

Comment: What version of IE? [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) reports that this is unavailable in IE<10, and only then with the `-ms-` prefix.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I've got version 11 running right now. the -ms-prefix is working for the display preference, but the background color doesn't stretch across the whole menu. Just the first element

Comment: Some features will not work on other browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873753/css-alternative-for-displaybox-for-ie-and-opera

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flexible box model - display : flex, box, flexbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662578/flexible-box-model-display-flex-box-flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

These are not the part of css2 they are introduced in css3

so wont work in older version of IE (6,7,8)

and

```
display: flex; // is not supported in older IE version
display: -webkit-box;  // is for chrome not IE
display: -ms-flexbox;  // is not supported in older IE version
```

For IE 11 i have seen in practical that it is using some of the properties from the IE7 may be they are using some the part of IE 7 rendering engine instead of IE 8/9/10 . i came across with some of the issues also like display , float so you should also see the doc. of IE 1!

for more reference visit : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm using IE 11, so display: flex; should work. And it does, it's just that the background color doesn't stretch past the first element.

Comment: -ms is for microsoft (trident, aka ie), -moz is for mozilla